# How to use if/ForEach in a SwiftUI View to show IAP modal?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display a **Subscribe Now** modal view instantly after the app starts to encourage users to subscribe to the Pro In-App Purchase, so I used the `.onAppear` modifier, and it works fine **only if** I want to show the modal every time the app starts.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    @State private var showModal = false
    @ObservedObject var storeManager: StoreManager
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Contents Here
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.selection = "Pro"
            self.showModal.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            if self.selection == "Pro" {
                Pro(showModal: self.$showModal, storeManager: self.storeManager)
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(storeManager)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem begins when I want to display the modal **only** to those who have not subscribed yet to the Pro IAP, so I modified `.onAppear` to:

```
        .onAppear {
            ForEach(storeManager.myProducts, id: \.self) { product in
                VStack {
                    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: product.productIdentifier) {
                        self.selection = "Pro"
                        self.showModal.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But, the `if` and `ForEach` seems not to work smoothly with structs and views. How should I use them in my case?

**Update:**

Based on the answers, I have changed the loop inside `.onAppear` to make the code conforms to SwiftUI requirements:

```
.onAppear {
    storeManager.myProducts.forEach { product in
    // Alternatively, I can use (for in) loop:
    // for product in storeManager.myProducts {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: product.productIdentifier) {
            self.selection = "Pro"
            self.showModal.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, errors have gone away but the modal is not displayed on startup.

I discovered that the problem is, `storeManager.myProducts` is not loaded in `.onAppear` modifier, while it's loaded correctly when I put the same loop in a button instead of .onAppear, any ideas? Why does onAppear doesn't load the IAP? Where should I put the code to make the modal run when the view loaded?

**Update 2:**

Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

App:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Reprod_SOFApp: App {
    @StateObject var storeManager = StoreManager()
    let productIDs = ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]

    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: Reprod_SOFDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document, storeManager: storeManager)
                .onAppear() {
                    storeManager.getProducts(productIDs: productIDs)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: Reprod_SOFDocument
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    @State private var showModal = false
    @ObservedObject var storeManager: StoreManager
    var test = ["t"]

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            .onAppear {
                // storeManager.myProducts.forEach(id: \.self) { product in
                // Alternatively, I can use (for in) loop:
                 for i in test {
                     if !i.isEmpty {
                        self.selection = "Pro"
                        self.showModal.toggle()
                     }
                 }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                if self.selection == "Pro" {
                    Modal(showModal: self.$showModal, storeManager: self.storeManager)
                        .onAppear(perform: {
                                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(storeManager)
                        })
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Modal:

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct  Modal: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    @ObservedObject var storeManager: StoreManager

    var body: some View {
        Text("hello world")
    }
}
```

StoreManager:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    
    @Published var myProducts = [SKProduct]()
    var request: SKProductsRequest!
    @Published var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                transactionState = .purchasing
            case .purchased:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .purchased
            case .restored:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .restored
            case .failed, .deferred:
                print("Payment Queue Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error))")
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    transactionState = .failed
                    default:
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Did receive response")
        
        if !response.products.isEmpty {
            for fetchedProduct in response.products {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myProducts.append(fetchedProduct)
                }
            }
        }
        
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print("Invalid identifiers found: \(invalidIdentifier)")
        }
    }
        
    func getProducts(productIDs: [String]) {
        print("Start requesting products ...")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIDs))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Request did fail: \(error)")
    }
    
    func purchaseProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        } else {
            print("User can't make payment.")
        }
    }
    
    func restoreProducts() {
        print("Restoring products ...")
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
                      
}
```

[Here is a link to Minimal Reproducible Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yzWnLRzSKrDt-4TWaCc3I6pfyZNh7fT1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.onAppear` modifier to display the modal, you can change the initial values of `selection` and `showModal`:

```
@State private var selection: String? = "Pro"
@State private var showModal = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") ? true : false
// Write your product identifier instead of "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This way, modal view will be shown instantly after the content view loads.

**Note:** For `showModal`, I've applied a conditional `if` instead of simply `true`, since you said you want to show the modal **only** to those who have not subscribed yet to the Pro IAP.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to separate logic into a viewmodel, and you only need to manage one identified object to show your pro modal.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchStatus)
            .sheet(item: $viewModel.carrier) { carrier in
                ModalView(storeManager: carrier.storeManager)
            }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var carrier: ModalObject?
    
    private let storeManager: StoreManager

    func fetchStatus() {
        // do something asynchronous like
        storeManager.fetchProducts() { [self] products in
            if !products.contains(proProducts) {
                self.carrier = ModalObject(storeManager: self.storeManager)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalObject: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let storeManager: StoreManager
}
```

I just wrote without compiling, please check with your xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.onAppear{}` should be Swift code instead `SwiftUI (ForEach, VStack)`.  VStack are view structs.

Comment: Please see the updated question.